# Custom font for holoviews hv.Text is not adopted in Word

Tags: fonts, ms-word, cpu-word, holoviews

I want to change the font of a hv.Text element and use it within a figure in a Word document.

For example, when I use the following code:

```py
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
from bokeh.io import export_svg

plot = hv.Curve([(0, 1), (2, 1)]) * hv.Text(1, 2, 'Test').options(text_font='Times New Roman')

plot_state = hv.renderer('bokeh').get_plot(plot).state
plot_state.output_backend = 'svg'
export_svg(plot_state, filename='test.svg')
```

And paste the reulting `test.svg` into my Word document it does not adopt the custom font, in this case Times New Roman:

[image]

The desired output (in Word) would be:

[image]

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't quite understand it, I was able to solve the problem with a workaround as follows:
Save the created SVG as a PDF using Chrome and the included PDF printer and then convert this PDF back into an SVG using an online tool. Then it worked, even in Word.

If anyone has a more intuitive solution, I would be very grateful!